# Program reads file but "skips" lines when they shouldn't be skipped

Tags: c, struct

So basically I have a program that reads in a specific format of a file as shown:

```
P3
# CREATOR: GIMP PNM Filter Version 1.1
400 530
255
189
165
181
181
156
...
```

My program reads in the first line as the format of the file, then any comments starting with a '#', then the width and height, then the max rgb value and then any other rgb values.

**NOTE:** the part reading in the rgb values is incomplete so ignore this for my question. Now to my issue..

The output i want is as shown as the exact file format, but the result i get is as follows:

```
P3
# CREATOR: GIMP PNM Filter Version 1.1
255 189
165
```

As you can see, it completely skips the width and height values and uses the next 2 values in place of it for some reason...

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COMMENT_LENGTH 256
#define COMMENT_ARRAY_SIZE 10
#define MAX_PIXEL_HEIGHT 480
#define MAX_PIXEL_WIDTH 640

typedef struct PPM {
    char format[2]; //2 letter code for PPM format
    char comments[COMMENT_LENGTH][COMMENT_ARRAY_SIZE]; //comment array
    int width; //number of columns
    int height; //number of rows
    int max; //maximum colour value (usually 255)
    int rgbPixels[MAX_PIXEL_WIDTH * MAX_PIXEL_HEIGHT][3]; //integers between 0 and max for pixel i's RGB values
}PPM;

struct PPM * getPPM(FILE *fd);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *file = fopen("ape.ppm", "r");
    if(file == NULL) return 0;
    else {
        struct PPM *newPPM = getPPM(file);

        return 0;
    }
}

struct PPM * getPPM(FILE *fd) {
    if(fd == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    struct PPM *newPPMFile = (PPM *) malloc(sizeof(PPM));

    fscanf(fd, "%2s\n", newPPMFile->format);
    printf("%2s\n", newPPMFile->format);

    //check for comments
    int i = 0;
    char str[COMMENT_LENGTH];
    while(i < COMMENT_ARRAY_SIZE && fgets(str, COMMENT_LENGTH, fd) != NULL) {
        if(str[0] != '#') {
            break;
        } else {
            strcpy(newPPMFile->comments[i], str);
            printf("%s", newPPMFile->comments[i]);
        }
    }

    //read width and height
    fscanf(fd, "%d %d", &newPPMFile->width, &newPPMFile->height);
    printf("%d %d\n", newPPMFile->width, newPPMFile->height);

    //read max
    fscanf(fd, "%d", &newPPMFile->max);
    printf("%d\n", newPPMFile->max);

    //read rgb data in rgb array (INCOMPLETE)


    //close file
    fclose(fd);

    return newPPMFile;
};
```

Comment: You need a `n+1` size array to store a string of length `n`.

Comment: NEVER cast the result of malloc. and you should stick to one definition (`PPM` or `struct PPM`), do not mix.

Comment: When you decide whether a line is a comment or not, you have already read that line. You break, but the file offset is after that line. So your next scanned number is 255, of course. (In my opinion it's a good idea not to mix `fscanf` and `fgets`, because both treat new-line characters differently.)

Comment: @MOehm Okay i understand that.. but how could I fix the offset issue?

Comment: Why do you `typedef` `PPM, if you still use `struct PPM` only? Either `typedef` or use `struct` namespace, but not both; that is just confusing. One of the major rules in programming is to express consistently.

Comment: the `argc` and `argv[]` parameters are not used (raises compiler warnings) suggest the main() signature be: `int main( void )`

Comment: the closing brace of the function is followed by a semicolon `;`.  (raises compiler warning) suggest removing the trailing semicolon `;`

Comment: making the tag name of a struct that same as a typedef name for that struct can be handled by a modern compiler, but leads to confusion for the human reader. (in the case, even the OP is being confused.)  Suggest making the names different

Comment: there is a unused variable `newPPM` (raises compiler warning) which is an indication of sloppy coding.   Suggest, when compiling to always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pdenatic` (I also use: `-Wconversion -std=c99)

Comment: when calling `malloc()` `realloc()` or `calloc()` 1) in C, the returned value has type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling the `scanf()` family of function (I.E. `fscanf()`) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding this line: `if(file == NULL) return 0;`  1) this tells the user NOTHING about what happened in the execution of the code. 2) the `0` return value is telling the system that the execution was successful (no errors).   3) placing the literal on the `rvalue` means a keypunch error, like entering `=` rather than `==` will be accepted by the compiler and be a major pain to debug.  4) not a good idea to call the variable name the same as the struct name with only capitalization difference. (cont)

Comment: (cont)  Suggest: `if( NULL == file ) { perror( "fopen for ape.ppm failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`   Note: the call to `perror()` outputs to stderr and will also output the message indicating why the OS thinks the call to fopen() failed.  calling `exit( EXIT_FAILURE )` will let the OS/shell/etc. know that the program did not execute successfully,.

Comment: in the function: `getPPM()` there is no need to check the parameter, as the `main()` function already checked it.

Comment: regarding this line: `fscanf(fd, "%2s\n", newPPMFile->format);` the format specifier '%2s'  will read the two characters, the (because it is a %s format specifier) always append a NUL byte.   This will overflow the 'format' input buffer.  this results in undefined behaviour.  Suggest: `fscanf(fd, "%2c ", newPPMFile->format);` --or-- fscanf(fd, "%c%c ", newPPMFile->format[0]. newPPMFile->format[1] );`  (notice the trailing space char in the format string) which will input 2 characters and consume the trailing `white space`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgets` reads the full line into the buffer. It it doesn't begin with a hash mark, you lose the data on that line.

A solution is to use `fscanf` throughout. `fscanf` stops scanning when the pattern isn't matched or if a conversion can't be made. So if you enforce a hash mark before the comment, but the line doesn't begin with a hash mark, the rest of the line is untouched:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int width, height, max;
    char buf[80];                             // temporary buffer
    FILE *fd = fopen("kk", "r");

    if(fd == NULL) return 1;                  // TODO: Error message

    fscanf(fd, "%79s", buf);
    if (strcmp(buf, "P3") != 0) return 1;     // TODO: Error message

    while (fscanf(fd, " # %79[^\n]%*[^\n]", buf) == 1) {
        printf("Comment: %s\n", buf);
    }

    fscanf(fd, "%d %d", &width, &height);     // TODO: Check success
    printf("%d x %d\n", width, height);

    fscanf(fd, "%d", &max);                   // TODO: Check success
    printf("max: %d\n", max);

    fclose(fd);    
    return 0;
}
```

There are some things to keep in mind, though:

- `fscanf` does not care or know about new lines; new-line characters are just white space. That means that your first hash mark could be on the same line with the file format `P3`.
- What is an advantage in reading the comments may be a pitfall when you read the values: The code above doesn't check whether a conversion was made. That's not good, especially that if you read `EOF` or a string that isn't an integer, `fscanf` gets stuck.
- The format `%79[^\n]` will read only up to 79 characters. If the comment line is longer, the file position will not be on the new-line character, this srewing up the reading of subsequent lines. To circumvent that, you can add `%*[^\n]` after that: This will enforce that you read to the next new-line character, but it won't store the results. (`*` means "don't store result" in `scanf` formats.) That way you get up to the first 80 characters of each comment line and also ensure that the line is read completely if it is longer.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why for the rest of us...?

Comment: There is an issue with reading comments though.. It only reads one of the comments. Is there a way to get round this issue? I tried things like: `while (fscanf(fd, "%79[^\n]", buf) >= 1) { }` and `while(.. != 0)` but I can't get it to work

Comment: The program above reads multiple comments all right, but there is an issue if the comment exceeds the prescribes line length of currently 80 chars. I've added a fix.

Comment: using `fscanf()` ( with the suggested format string ) will fail to read a complete comment line because such lines contain `white space` and the input will stop upon encountering the white space

Comment: @user3629249: No, it won't. The `%s` format scans words delimited by white space. The `%[` format, which is used to scan a comment hehe, will scan as long as the characters match, in this case until a new-line (or the end of the input) is encountered. For what it's worth, I've tested the program above with the given input and also with multiple, very long lines. The reading is a rough draft (and it misses many checks), but the point raised in the question, namely reading the comments without swallowing data lines, works.

Comment: Your right, I was looking at the first call to `fscanf()` and thinking that was reading a comment.  Sorry, my error

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things here:

```
while(i < COMMENT_ARRAY_SIZE && fgets(str, COMMENT_LENGTH, fd) != NULL) {
    if(str[0] != '#') {
        break;
```

The position for the next read (offset) has already advanced, if you break or not. So naturally, it'll continue at the advanced offset, like you experienced here.

Also,

```
(PPM *) malloc(sizeof(PPM));
```

Casting the result of `malloc()` is unnecessary and potentially masks errors.

Comment: I understand both things you have said. Is there a way to move back from the advanced offset?

Answer (score 0):

1. Insufficient space [@errikos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900368/program-reads-file-but-skips-lines-when-they-shouldnt-be-skipped#comment57537188_34900368).

   ```
   // char format[2]; //2 letter code for PPM format
   char format[2 + 1]; //2 letter code for PPM format
   ...
   // 2 is the max width of non-white-space characters to scan
   fscanf(fd, "%2s\n", newPPMFile->format);
   ```
2. Check the return values form `fscanf()`

   ```
   // fscanf(fd, "%d %d", &newPPMFile->width, &newPPMFile->height);
   if (fscanf(fd, "%d %d", &newPPMFile->width, &newPPMFile->height) != 2) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Error reading width & height\n");
   }
   ```
3. Code mixes `fscanf()` with `fgets()`.  Tis often is a problem as many formats used to not consume that trailing ``` '\n`` and then a following ```fgets()`simply reads just that one character.  Reccomedn only using`fgets()`.
4. Possibly other important issues too.

Answer (score 0):

here is the root of the problem.

in the loop reading comments:

when the line is read (when reading comments) that does not start with a #, then the code has already read width+height values from the input file.

So the code needs to parse those values from the `already read` line.